# How to save a folder of txt files as a variable in python

Tags: python, text, permissions, text-analysis

I have a folder of txt folders that I want to import into python as a variable. Ideally, I want a variable 'profession_texts' where each txt file is an element in a list. This is what I have at the moment:

```
import os
profession_folder_path = '../fp/Updated/Profession/'
profession_files = os.listdir(profession_folder_path)
profession_texts = [open(profession_folder_path+file_name, encoding='utf-8').read() for file_name in profession_files]
print(profession_texts[0])
```

Yet, when running this script, I get the error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '../fp/Updated/Profession/Athlete'
```

So I have two problems. How do I get rid of this PermissionError? Once this error is resolved, will my code work for attaining my goal?

Comment: What are the permissions of ../fp/Updated/Profession/Athlete ? In a unix environment, you should be able to see using `stat <file or dir>`

Comment: I'm currently using a Jupyter notebook instead of a Unix environment so that code is giving a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to append file name with directory as (profession_folder_path+file_name). Use os.path.realpath(file_name) instead

```
import os
profession_folder_path = '../fp/Updated/Profession/'
profession_files = os.listdir(profession_folder_path)
profession_texts = [open(os.path.realpath(file_name)).read() for file_name in profession_files]
print(profession_texts[0])
```

and for permissions you need to have read permissions on file and execute permission on directory if you are using unix. Run below command:

```
chmod -R a+rx  '../fp/Updated/Profession/'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I do this, I receive the following error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '../history100s_2017/fp/Updated/Profession/'